# Does PACF plot shows the values greater than 1 or less than -1?

Tags: python, intervals, statsmodels, autocorrelation

When I plot PACF in python using statsmodels, it shows the values that are greater than 1.
Is it a normal thing or is there any error in this?

```
sm.graphics.tsa.plot_pacf(train, lags=20, ax=ax1)
```

I expect that it should show values between `-1` to `+1` i.e. the open interval `(-1,+1)`.